# Ionic: How to check if it's the first screen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Searching for this, but found no answer. I wanted to have a condition in Ionic/AngularJS that checked if it was the very first screen that opened, on application launch.

On a registerBackButtonAction action, I wanted to check for a specific state if it was the very first screen, or if it was an other moment of the lifecycle of the application.

Other suggestions for approaching the problem are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$ionicView.enter`

> `$ionicView.enter` :  The view has fully entered and is now the active view. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached view.

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(event, data){
   // handle event or check state or whatever here
   console.log("State Params: ", data.stateParams);
});
```

Hope it helps